# How to link external css and js file from static block in magento 2.0

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to link css and jss file from static block in magento. my css file store in skin/frontend/rwd/default/css/mycss.css and js file store in js/myjs/filename.js.

i have made static block in magento 2.0 and want to link these files from static block

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please show what you have done so far.

Comment: As per Magento 2 file structure, there is no skin folder. Also, all the files are in less as per standards and not in CSS. To link CSS you can use xml files as it is not possible in magento 2 to add from static block. Also you need to use requirejs for js files.